# how to create a proxy for SMS Gateway

Tags: java, testing, sms-gateway, http-proxy, shared-directory

We have a mailsserver, for which we have created a simplSocketproxy in form of a batch file, which looks so:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Proxy_for_SMTP_MailServer
echo Proxy for SMTP MailServer
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
set CURR_DIR=C:\gcdm\projects\trunk\SimpleSocketProxy\target
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
echo Current directory is: %CURR_DIR%
REM LMUC439844.muc:11580

call java.exe -classpath %CURR_DIR%\SimpleSocketProxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.bmw.c2b.failout.proxy.socket.SocketProxy 25 tcp://smuc4625.muc:25
PAUSE
```

The default DB value look so:

`Key:config.componentContext.gcdm-notification-ejb.cdp.sms.endpoint.alternate.url`                                                                      `value:http://smuc4625.muc/sms2mail.py`

And so we do have only to replace the value (value:http://smuc4625.muc/sms2mail.py) with our local maschine (LMUC439844.muc) (look above),and it becomes so:

```
`Key:config.componentContext.gcdm-notification-jb.cdp.sms.endpoint.alternate.url                                                                   
`value:LMUC439343.muc`
```

and do a commit, and restart the server, and start the proxy (batch file), and then it work fine.
I want to do the same with the SMS Gateway, which look so in the DB as default:

`Key:config.componentContext.gcdm-notification-ejb.sambaShareFolder`                                                                   `value:smb://GW070021.w7/GCDM/`

and after it was replaced with my local maschine,it look so:

`Key:config.componentContext.gcdm-notification-ejb.sambaShareFolder`                                                                   `value:LMUC439343.muc`

But it did not work, and like so i did set my host on my proxy, but it did not work though:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Proxy_for_SMS_Server
echo Proxy for SMS_Server
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
set CURR_DIR=C:\gcdm\projects\trunk\SimpleSocketProxy\target
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
echo Current directory is: %CURR_DIR%

REM LMUC439844.muc:443

call java.exe -classpath %CURR_DIR%\SimpleSocketProxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.bmw.c2b.failout.proxy.socket.SocketProxy 434 tcp://GW070021.w7:445
PAUSE
```

The different what I notice between the values of both SMS and SMTP in the DB,the SMTP is a url: `http://smuc4625.muc/sms2mail.py`, and the SMS is sharedFolder:`smb://GW070021.w7/GCDM/`

could it be the reason why it did not work?

Answer (score 0):

The administration of the SMS gateway is done using Internet Explorer. If you have a proxy server, you might have to configure it to allow access to the administration interface. This guide gives you the steps to take/

To bypass the proxy setting to access the administration interface of the SMS gateway, you have to open the Internet Options form in Internet Explorer. This form contains a "Connections" tab that allow you configure the "Lan settings". In the Lan settings form, click on the "Advanced" button in the "Proxy server" group box. This will bring up the proxy server configuration form. In the Proxy server configuration form you need to enter "127.0.0.1; localhost" into the exceptions textbox.

Comment: my application does not run over the internet explorer,it is  only a sms-gateway which forward sms to mobile devices,and it has nothing to do with IE Browser.I have vugen script which send SMS through this SMS Gateway, and I want to replace it with a Proxy similar to "SimpleSocketProxy" like the example of the SMTP I described above